# Are there any tools for Craft similar to the Yii Code Generator?

Tags: plugin-development

There is Yii demo tutorial at http://www.yiiframework.com/screencasts/ that uses the Yii Code Generator. Are there similar Code Generator tools in Craft?

Answer (score 3):

There are third-party code generators, such as the [Element Type Generator](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/element-type-generator) or the [Craft Plugin Generator](https://github.com/timkelty/generator-craft-plugin)

You also have the [migration tools](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/migrations) that generate code. Using the querygen command you can output Records as db query commands.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're referring to [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii), Yii's CRUD code generation tool.  We specifically removed that from Craft.

I'm not aware of any Craft-specific code generation tools.

Comment: Sad to hear, this is a big plus in the yii world